# Android Broadcast own message

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, broadcast

Is it possible to broadcast any message from any Service which is running in background so that any broadcast receiver from that app or any other app can receive the message?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you refactor your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The broadcastreceivers must have some filter and if your broadcast doesn't set this filter your broadcast wouldn't receive the broadcast.

So if you would like to send some message to all of your broadcastreceivers, then all of them should have the same filter properties, but then they are unnecessary.

See the documentation for further details.

> When you use sendBroadcast(Intent) or related methods, normally any other application can receive these broadcasts. You can control who can receive such broadcasts through permissions described below. 
>   -> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. The service should send a specific message, and only the apps that listen for that message will intercept it.

Comment: Can you give some sample code how to broadcast it and how to receive it?